# After hitting send button the form submits but how do I redirect to new page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my form code. After hitting send I'd like to see a confirmation message or redirect to a different page.

```
<%= flash[:notice]

<%= form_with(url: "/static_pages/thank_you") do |form| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :name %>
        <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Name" %>
      </div>        
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :email, "Email Address" %>
        <%= form.text_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Email" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label :message %>
        <%= form.text_area :message, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Message" %>
      </div>        
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= form.submit "Send" %> 
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller code or at least the start of it. I'm suspecting I'm missing something on the page below.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

    def index
    #@products = Product.all
    end

  def landing_page
    @products = Product.limit(4)
    end

    def contact
    end

    def about
    end

    def thank_you
    @name = params[:name]
        @email = params[:email]
    @message = params[:message]
    UserMailer.contact_form(@email, @name, @message).deliver_now
    end

end
```

Comment: where do you want to redirect this page? can you share your controller code?

Comment: yes just added it, please let me know if anything else could help.

Comment: i m asking you on which page you want to redirect it?

Comment: Lets try the given solution and you can redirect it according to you, for now i have redirected it `root_path`

Answer (score 0):

```
def thank_you
  @name = params[:name]
  @email = params[:email]
  @message = params[:message]
  UserMailer.contact_form(@email, @name, @message).deliver_now
  flash[:notice] = "Mail sent successfully!"
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Thank-you!! That worked, I can can get the rest from here. New to Rails, so sometimes a little clarification like this is all I need to get back on track :-) If I could upvote your answer I would.

Comment: :) Feel free to upvote/accept answer if it helped you,thanks